# Watch and accelerometer-what you can really do?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

It seems to me that there is some kind of wrong perception of the `WatchOS` abilities.

After reading all the Apple docs, and exploring, this is what i know :

1. No gyroscope or magnetometer (compass) API's , which means there are so many things you can't know without them about the user.
2. The accelerometer, is only working when the app is in the foreground/background for limited time.
3. If you want to know what happened during the day with the watch , you can check your `Health app`, and get some picture about the accelerometer.

**The thing about 3,** is due to limited power consumption, **you don't get high sampling rate**, as you would get when the app is in foreground , which means again ,you can't know even with the accelerometer whats really happening during the day. catching the small gestures .

Am i wrong about something here assuming the `WatchOS 2.1` ?
Can you really learn about a user without these abilities ? for example like what you get in the `Jawbone` app ?

The "fitness" thing is not really there, developers can't barely do nothing .

Comment: Seems like more of a rant than a question, and the way it's phrased now, the answers will primarily be opinion-based and/or too broad.  Can you edit this to focus the question on something specific that you want to do?

Comment: There is a question mark, twice, can you confirm that the watchOS is working like that for the sake of other developers that read that? Or just to discuss whether its defined as a question or a rant or some other not relevant robotic defenition?